# Blog Post Ellipses CSS

Tags: blogs, posts

Sorry if this question is a little basic - I'm rather new.

I am using a drag and drop website creator (Weebly), and I am working on the blog section. I want to do something like [this blog does](http://https:/https://www.frugalwoods.com/), with each post trailing off with a "..." when a certain amount of lines are used up so the visitor sees a whole list of posts instead of having to scroll all the way through a post to get to the next one. (I don't need to do the slideshow thing with the posts though, I'm just interested in the condensed list idea).

I presume this is a CSS thing, but I could be totally off base on that. Could someone please give me some suggestions? And is there a name for this specific task?

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the text is hidden with CSS or if the text is just actually not present by using your browser's dev tools.  In most browsers, you can right-click the place you want to check out, then click "inspect" to open the developer tools, where you'll be able to see the underlying data of the page.  If that tree contains text that cuts off with an ellipsis like you see on the page, then the text is just actually not there; it's not hidden with CSS.

I would venture a name for this task as a blog post "preview", "excerpt", or "truncation".